# How to make page numbering at the bottom of web-site?

Tags: html, css

Do you know how to make a page numbering like this? (link is below) with floats or with positioning and it should be on bottom of the web-site and must not interrupt the content above, I tried several things but can't figure out. Anyone can help?
[So This is the numbering I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cymgt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#pages-numbers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#pages-numbers a {
  background-color: cyan;
  color: blue;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium. Vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut. Orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. Pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut. Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse. Sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet. Ac tincidunt vitae semper quis. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor.
  </p>
  <p>
    Massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan. Neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo. Diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum. Elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis. Donec adipiscing tristique risus nec. Turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Sed odio morbi quis commodo.
  </p>
  <p>
    Pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis. Nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium viverra. Nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate. Lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a. Aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit. Ut porttitor leo a diam. Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget. A diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. In nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut.
  </p>
  <p>
    Orci eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc. Vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis. Ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas. Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus. Tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante. Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra. Mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium.
  </p>
  <p>
    Fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent. Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Potenti nullam ac tortor vitae. Duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis. In nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="pages-numbers">
  <a href="/pages/page1.html">1</a><a href="/pages/page2.html">2</a><a href="/pages/page3.html">3</a>
  <a href="/pages/page4.html">4</a><a href="/pages/page5.html">5</a><a href="/pages/page6.html">6</a>
  <a href="/pages/page7.html">7</a><a href="/pages/page8.html">8</a><a href="/pages/page9.html">9</a>
  <a href="/pages/page10.html">10</a><a href="/pages/page11.html">11</a><a href="/pages/page12.html">12</a>
  <a href="/pages/page13.html">13</a><a href="/pages/page14.html">14</a><a href="/pages/page15.html">15</a>
  <a href="/pages/page16.html">16</a><a href="/pages/page17.html">17</a><a href="/pages/page18.html">18</a>
  <a href="/pages/page19.html">19</a><a href="/pages/page20.html">20</a><a href="/pages/page21.html">21</a>
  <a href="/pages/page22.html">22</a><a href="/pages/page23.html">23</a><a href="/pages/page24.html">24</a>
  <a href="/pages/page25.html">25</a><a href="/pages/page26.html">26</a><a href="/pages/page27.html">27</a>
  <a href="/pages/page28.html">28</a><a href="/pages/page29.html">29</a><a href="/pages/page30.html">30</a>
  <a href="/pages/page31.html">31</a><a href="/pages/page32.html">32</a>
</div>
```